# Is there a general formula for $\sin{(\frac{n \pi}{2})}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a general formula for $\displaystyle{\sin{(\frac{n \pi}{2})}}$?

For even $n$ it's equal to $0$, but for odd $n$ it's equal to $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: $$\frac{i^n - (-i)^n}{2i}$$

Comment: Certainly there is, other than that formula. What other functions would you use? When I was a kid I programmed in BASIC where the built-in functions did include `sin` but also such things as `int` and `abs`... oeis.org is also interesting.

Answer (score 3):

$\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})=(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1}\frac{-1+(-1)^{n}}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

How about $(\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{2})(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$